# configuration ':sharedkmm:podDebugFrameworkIosArm64' and [configuration ':sharedkmm:debugFrameworkIosArm64'] contain identical attribute sets

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

My build.gradle.kts:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
    kotlin("native.cocoapods")
}

kotlin {
    android() {
        publishLibraryVariants("release")
    }
    
    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "sharedkmm"
        }
    }

    cocoapods {
        version = "1.0"
        summary = "sharedkmm"
        homepage = "sharedkmm"
        ios.deploymentTarget = "10.0"
        podfile = project.file("../iosApp/Podfile")
        pod("SSZipArchive") {
            version = "2.2.3"
        }
        pod("Reachability")
        framework {
            baseName = "sharedkmm"
            isStatic = false
            embedBitcode("disable")
        }

    }
```

I got error when I kmm project to Podfile:
My Podfile:
pod 'sharedkmm', :path => '../KMMDemo1/sharedkmm'

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':sharedkmm:linkPodDebugFrameworkIosSimulatorArm64'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':sharedkmm:iosSimulatorArm64CompileKlibraries'.
> Consumable configurations with identical capabilities within a project (other than the default configuration) must have unique attributes, but configuration ':sharedkmm:podDebugFrameworkIosArm64' and [configuration ':sharedkmm:debugFrameworkIosArm64'] contain identical attribute sets. Consider adding an additional attribute to one of the configurations to disambiguate them.  Run the 'outgoingVariants' task for more details. See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/userguide/upgrading_version_7.html#unique_attribute_sets for more details.

I try to integrate :shared in xcode. But it not working.

Comment: Please read the comments from https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-55751